# Error while i post on friends wall

Tags: android

while i am using this code for post, i got error on calling **request**.. if I fix this the default AsynchronousRunner code in face book will be changed.

```
protected void postToWall(String temp2) {
   System.out.println("<<inside the post method>>");
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("message", _messageInput.getText().toString()"some text Here);
   params.putString("caption", "{*actor*} just posted a secret message.");
   params.putString("description","A secret message is waiting for you.  Click the link to    decode it.");
   params.putString("name", "A Secret Message For You");
 params.putString("picture","http://www.kxminteractive.com/Content/images/app_logos/secretMessage.png");
  params.putString("link", "http://www.kxminteractive.com/decrypt/");
  **mAsyncRunner.request(((temp2 == null) ? "me" : temp2) + "/feed",
                params, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener());**
}
```

Comment: Next time,be sure you post code in proper format which looks very much readable. See above, i have done by selecting code and then press CTRL+K.

Comment: I am new to this site so this mistake was happen..

Comment: I know thats why i have suggested the shortcut key CTRL+K to format code. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code..i put the **stream.publish** method inside the request function..it works well..

```
 protected void postToWall(String temp2) {
   System.out.println("<<inside the post method>>");
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("message", _messageInput.getText().toString()"some text Here);
   params.putString("caption", "{*actor*} just posted a secret message.");
   params.putString("description","A secret message is waiting for you.  Click the link to    decode it.");
   params.putString("name", "A Secret Message For You");
 params.putString("picture","http://www.kxminteractive.com/Content/images/app_logos/secretMessage.png");
  params.putString("link", "http://www.kxminteractive.com/decrypt/");
  **mAsyncRunner.request(((temp2 == null) ? "me" : temp2) + "/feed",
                params, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener(),stream.publish);**
}
```